# gestureLock can't draw in wrong state

Tags: android

I made a gestureLock on Android by a custom view which extends viewgroup, as unusally, a gesturelock has three state: normal, pressed and wrong. I can bring about the first two state in my gestureLock, but I can't draw wrong state, that is I can't draw the red line when in wrong state, it shows like this:

[image]

How can I fix the wrong state in my gestureLock?

[my project source code](https://github.com/haipinghuang/Asop)

Comment: As per the official close reasons here, we need _the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_. Would you paste in the code that readers need to see?

Comment: If you can draw the pressed state, why not the wrong state? Just changing color?